# PHP: how to reuse code (oop)?

Tags: php, oop

I have studied in php oop and stocked in the concept of reusable code.

I have seen an  example like

```
interface iTemplate
{
    public function setVariable($name, $var);
    public function getHtml($template);
}
And implement it:

// Implement the interface
class Template implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function setVariable($name, $var)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $var;
    }

    public function getHtml($template)
    {
        foreach($this->vars as $name => $value) {
            $template = str_replace('{' . $name . '}', $value, $template);
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

I can understand the code but not sure why it is reusable. Every time I want to add a new function in iTemplate interface, my Template class needs to be changed too. I don't understand the concept of "reuse". I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: can u tell me where did u find that code? I'm in the learning stage and I look to learn by examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interfaces aren't directly for code reuse.  They are for abstraction.  They enable classes that use the template to check for the interface instead of the base template class.  That way it separates implementation from the interface declaration.

So if your method does something with a `template` class, checking for an object of instance `template` would hard code a dependency on that class.  But in reality you don't care what class you get, you just care if it adheres to the `iTemplate` interface (since that's all you're calling anyway).

```
public function foo(Template $template) {
```

vs:

```
public function foo(iTemplate $template) {
```

Now, as far as code re-use, interfaces aren't really designed for that.  Inheritance typically is.  Basically think of inheritance as extending an abstraction.  Let me give you an example:

If you were to create a set of classes for birds, you could approach it with inheritance and without it.  Let's see how we might do it without:

```
interface iBird {
    public function fly();
    public function speak();
    public function swim();
    public function walk();
}

class Duck implements iBird {
    public function fly() {
        //Fly here
    }
    public function speak() {
        // Quack here
    }
    public function swim() {
        //Swim here
    }
    public function walk() {
        //Walk here
    }
}

class Turkey implements iBird {
    public function fly() {
        //Fly here, but limited
    }
    public function speak() {
        //Make turkey sound here
    }
    public function swim() {
        throw new Exception('Turkeys can not swim!');
    }
    public function walk() {
        //Walk here
    }
}
```

Now, this is a simple example, but you can see that in those two birds, the `walk()` functions will likely be identical (and hence violate DRY)...

Let's see how that might look with a single tier inheritance:

```
abstract class Bird implements iBird {
    public function fly() {
        //Fly here
    }
    abstract public function speak();
    public function swim() {
        //Swim here
    }
    public function walk() {
        //Walk here
    }
}

class Duck extends Bird {
    public function speak() {
        //Quack here
    }
} 

class Turkey extends Bird {
    public function speak() {
        //Make turkey sound here
    }
    public function swim() {
        throw new Exception('Turkeys can not swim!');
    }
}
```

Now, you can see we just re-used 3 of the methods!  We didn't declare `speak()`, since it will be always overriden (since no two birds sound alike).

Sounds good right?  Well, depending on our needs, we may want to add other abstract types.  So lets say we were making a lot of different types of birds...  We would have some that didn't swim, so we might create an abstract class `NonSwimmingBird` that extends `Bird`, but throws the exception for us.  Or a `NonFlyingBird`, or a `ShortRangeBird`...

Now, we're really on the track as far as code re-use, but we're hitting a wall in another area.  Suppose we have a bird that doesn't fly or swim.  What class do we inherit from?  Either way, we're duplicating code.  So we need to find another way out.  Well, how do we do it?  Through [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science))...  Instead of direct inheritance, we could use a decorator pattern to add those traits on the fly.  (There are other patterns that can be used here, the point is to show that inheritance alone won't suit all needs.  And Patterns alone won't either.  You need a good architecture using both worlds based upon what your exact needs are)...

The point is, it all depends on your needs.  If you only have 2 "classes" of objects you're going to architect something much simpler than if you are planning on having thousands.  The point of what I wrote here is to demonstrate how you can use straight inheritance to enforce some DRY principals (but also how straight inheritance can cause code duplication as well).  The big thing, is don't try to stick to DRY just because you don't want to repeat yourself.  Stick to DRY, but make sure that you're combining and extending where it's reasonable to, otherwise you're creating yourself a maintenance headache.  Stick to the [Single Responsibility Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Interface writes only 1 time in beginning of development. And only after this writes other classes implements of this Interface. Interface - is a fundament.
Note: method setVariable isn't required. There are good magic methods in PHP as `__get()`, and `__set()`.

Comment: Thanks. but let's say we create another class called Product implement iTemplate. I still have to type setVariable and getHtml method in my class with or without implementing interface, so what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are usually useful in cases where you want something to be interchangeable. Imagine you'd build a Plugin aware application. You then have the interface iPlugin:

```
interface iPlugin {
   public function init();
   /* .. */
}
```

and all Plugins would implement that interface. A plugin manager could then easily check if a Plugin implements the interface and call the init() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Code doesn't need to be OO to be reusable, although in many cases that helps.

Code certainly doesn't need to use interfaces to be reusable, although again in some cases that will help.

The key to writing reusable code is to write code that is clearly written, well-commented, uses consistent naming and calling conventions, and is more general than it strictly needs to be for the problem at hand.

One of the simplest and most powerful techniques for writing reusable code in PHP is writing methods that accept either a variable number of arguments, or accept an associative array of parameters.

Often, code that didn't start out "intending" to be reusable turns out to be something you'll want to reuse. Typically, code starts "inline" and then you discover you need to do exactly, or nearly exactly, the same thing in more than one place. When you find yourself copying and pasting code it's time to refactor it as a function.

Similarly, when you find yourself wishing a function you had defined in file X would be really helpful in file Y, it's time to move it into a module.

The best way to learn all this is by experience. Some people will tell you to architect this stuff from the beginning, and that's certainly a good idea if you have the insight and experience to do so, but it's just as valid to do so from the bottom up, and it's probably the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Reusability of Object oriented Programming is the use of previous class or function or method in the present class but no problem of previous class.